# Whats wrong with my drop down navigation menu? [possible ie issue]

Tags: html, css

Im trying to learn to build navigation menus using css. Ive stripped loads of tutorials down to the basics and got:

http://jsbin.com/osajiv/edit#html,live

When I mouse over the second link in firefox it drops down as expected however when I mouse over the link in ie it doesnt. Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style:

```
ul#nav:hover li ul
  {
    display: block;
  }
```

Change to

```
ul#nav li:hover ul
  {
    display: block;
  }
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/GYp74/

Comment: Thats really wierd the code you supplied works on jsfiddle but not on jsbin! ??? Is there a bug in it?

Comment: add ul{margin:0px; padding:0px;} in your css; left:0px; not-40px;